# Filtering inputs in Django admin input form

Tags: django, django-admin

Have found related answers, but cannot find anything covering my specific need.  I have only being using Django for about 2 weeks.   Have tried tutorial and the Django documentation.

Background. I have a database with different funds.   Each fund can have different performance
periods.   In each performance period there can be different series.   Each Performance period can
have flows for all the series defined within it.
Have set up relational db so that it filters down like that.   Problem is that
series names get re-used across performance periods (there is a seperate unique key).

I have models file that looks something like this:

```
class SeriesFlow(models.Model):
    series= models.ForeignKey(Series)
    date = models.DateField('date for flow')
    value = models.FloatField('Flow pos inflow, neg outflow')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.series)

class Series(models.Model):
    perf_period = models.ForeignKey(PerformancePeriod)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    series_longname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    # more fields
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.series
```

In the admin.py file i do the following relevant things:

```
class SeriesFlowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['series', 'date', 'value']
    list_display = ['series', 'date', 'value']
    list_filter = ['series__perf_period']   #nice __ syntax to go backwards

# and then registering the admin interfaces
admin.site.register(Fund, FundAdmin)
admin.site.register(PerformancePeriod, PerformancePeriodAdmin)
admin.site.register(Profit, ProfitAdmin)
admin.site.register(Series, SeriesAdmin)
admin.site.register(SeriesFlow, SeriesFlowAdmin)
```

The admin form allows my to filter series flows by the performance period which
is what I wqant to do.   when i try to add a series flow I get the three fields
that i want to enter series, date, value.   problem is, is that the dropdown 
gives the options for all the series in the database.   I want to filter the 
dropdown for series flow entering page so that it only gives the relevant series.
the series names displayed get reused between different funds and performance periods 
so the dropdown is a mess!   The filtered performance period is in the url of
the form so it is defiantely available.  just cant figure out how to filter for it.

URL for the series flow filtered and flow entry forms are:

```
admin/fee/seriesflow/?series__perf_period__id__exact=3  
admin/fee/seriesflow/add/?_changelist_filters=series__perf_period__id__exact%3D3
```

I the filtering is definitely still available.   now want to make sure that just the relevant series are displayed.  I add screen cap showing that series from other performance periods are also displayed in drop-down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your model relationship but formfield_for_foreignkey is what you need i think

```
class SeriesFlowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):                
        if db_field.name == 'series': kwargs['queryset'] = Series.objects.filter(series='xxx')
```